# What are the limit points and the interior points of $A= \{n \sin(1/n): n\in\mathbb{N}^+\}$. Is A closed or open?

Tags: general-topology

What are the limit points and the interior points of $A= \{n \sin(1/n): n\in\mathbb{N}^+\}$. Is A closed or open?

I'm confused. I think $A$ is neither closed and neither open.
Also I think the set of the limit points of $A$ is $[0,1]$,
and the set of the interior points of $A$  is $(0,1)$.
Please explain.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $\LaTeX$ syntax

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $\{n\sin(1/n)\}_{n\geq 1}$ is strictly increasing in $(0,1)$ and its limit, as $n\to\infty$, is $1$.

Threfore $A$ is not closed because $1\not \in A$, $A$ is not open because $A$ is a discrete set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way to see that $A$ is not open is to note that it is countable. Any interval on the real line is uncountable, so $A$ does not contain any interval, therefore it is not open.

Comment: @roberz what are the  limit point of A. Is 1 is only limit point. I think [0,1] are the limit points.

Comment: @Amit Let $x\in[0,1)$. Since $n\sin\frac{1}{n}$ is increasing ant it's limit is 1, as Robert Z pointed out, there is $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x<n\sin\frac{1}{n}$ for every $n\geq n_0$. Therefore, interval $(x-something positive,n_0\sin\frac{1}{n_0})$ contains finitely many members of the set $A$. Hence, $x$ is not a limit point of $A$.